# Mining with an AMD Graphics card

Tags: miner-configuration, gpu-mining

Following this tutorial here:

http://www.newslobster.com/random/how-to-get-started-using-your-gpu-to-mine-for-bitcoins-on-windows

And it says,

> *UPDATE*: If you are unsure, please download GPU Caps Viewer (I recommend the portable version) to determine if you have a compatible video device and a working version of OpenCL installed. If you are using an AMD/ATI card you likely need to install the ATI APP SDK (make sure you obtain the correct version for 32/64-bit Windows).

I've downloaded the SDK and installed it, but it's just sitting on my hd, doing nothing at all. I seem to be mining bit coins ok. Soft of confused as to what's going on? Thanks

Comment: is there a number with "MH/s" going across the bottom? if there is you are mining. you can also check your task manager too. There are a number of other tutorials out there as well. 
let me know and i can help you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are mining bitcoins successfully, then don't worry about it.

There's no need to install the SDK. OpenCL drivers are included with AMD's Catalyst drivers.

Also note that solomining on a GPU could mean you never make a single coin. It may look like now that it will take a couple years, but by that time the difficulty is much higher. Unless you are very lucky, you may never get anything at all. Try mining in a pool instead and think about getting ASIC.

Comment: I have a 4gb graphics card...would I still probably get nothing?

Comment: The amount of memory doesn't matter for mining bitcoins. Search this site for info on what hashrate you would get from your card.

Comment: Check you mh/s, look at this https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Mining_hardware_comparison, use one of on-line calculators like this http://www.coinish.com/calc/